# Extracting data from multiple csv's into a single dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have multiple csv files at a location. I want to extract two fields from each csv and append them all in one CSV.
Following is the info that i have in each CSV:

huh ///n ojwiehu hello :18: ddjhhfudhfuhughfugh :12N:
WIN 23459 Hondrus  juerheuhrhk
kji9 @! kfddhfhih9

This kind of information is there in each csv and i need to extract two fields:

1.) Text between :18: and :12N:
2.) Text between WIN and Hondrus

Output would contain 2 columns from each csv appended together into one dataframe

Can someone help me with the script.
Currently i am running the below code to extract the info from one of the csv. However, i would need a script which would extract info from all the CSV's and append them into one.

```
with open("data.csv", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
    text = fobj.read()
import re
a = re.compile(':18:(.*) :12N:')
b=re.compile('WIN(.*)HONDRUS')
z = a.findall(text)
k=b.findall(text)
print (z)
print (k)
```

Comment: I’m guessing the data is whitespace-delimited? Could you also share some of the data from another file, so that we can see the differences and similarities? You haven’t even specified whether the CSV files all have the same format, no? If this is CSV, why use RegEx?

Comment: The data is white space delimited. Data structure is same in all the files. Cant we use Regex in CSV?

Comment: You can, but isn’t the point of CSV that it follows a certain, organized, format? Are the `”:18:”` and `”:12N:”` always in the same column, or, rather, is the data you want always in the same column? Again, it’s difficult to say more with so little information about your data.

Comment: Is this you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59122468/11301900 ?

Answer (score 0):

Nitesh, you could use glob to grab all the files in an array that you can loop over:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.csv')
# ['1.csv',
# '2.csv',
# '3.csv',
# '4.csv']
```

Here's a modified version of your script that can put all of them into a list, which you can then write out line by line as a csv:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
strings = []
for file in files:
  with open(file, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
      text = fobj.read()
  import re
  a = re.compile(':18:(.*) :12N:')
  b=re.compile('WIN(.*)Hondrus')
  z = a.findall(text)
  k=b.findall(text)
  strings.append(z[0] + "," + k[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you share the complete script to extract two fields from each csv and append them all in one CSV. I am new to python, please help

Comment: Nitish, check out my update, let me know if you need further help, i'm glad to assist. you might need to update your regex to not capture the spaces, as i notice i think it is

Comment: I used the data you posted in your question so i changed my regex for HONDRUS to Hondrus, you might have to change that back, depending on how your actual data is.

Comment: Thanks for the script brother. I am facing two problems now: 1.) WIN and Hondrus occurs mutiple times in a single text file so the code is picking all the text between them, I just want the first occurence of that. Can you help? 2.) Once i get both the lists (z & k). How do i merge them into a single dataframe with two columns text_id(containing data from z) and WIN_ID(containing data from k) 3.) The last probem is that where there is no matching of the strings, i get an error. How can i stop that?

Comment: That import should be at the top of the file, always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` like @oppressionslayer suggested or you can use `sys` instead. Do something like this:

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

path = 'path_to_your_files'
files = [name for name in os.listdir(path)]

df = pd.Dataframe()

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,f),
 usecols=['18', '12N']) for f in files),
 ignore_index=True).reset_index()
```

Not sure if I got column names correctly. It would be helpful if you could provide a snippet of your data.

Comment: Not working says listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.pathlike or none     import sys
import pandas as pd

path=open(file, "r", encoding='UTF-8')
files = [name for name in os.listdir(path)]

df = pd.Dataframe()

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,f),
 usecols=[':20:', ':23B:']) for f in files),
 ignore_index=True).reset_index()

Comment: No, ```path``` variable should contain the path to the directory where files are contained, for example ```C:/Users/Admin/Documents/```. Also make sure to use either forward slash or double-backslash.